# Can I use a JCB credit card in the UK?

Tags: uk, japan, money, payment-cards

I am travelling in the UK from Japan next month. I was wondering if many places accept a JCB credit card.

Comment: Is your card branded Cirrus? Most ATMs in the UK accept MasterCard, Visa and Cirrus cards. JCB isn’t very well-known in the UK so the number of shops, restaurants etc accepting it may be limited, especially outside London. You should ask your bank for advice.

Comment: JCB has a reciprocal agreement with Diners Club, so I think you might be fine. Diners Club acceptance in the UK isn't particularly high either, but high enough I think.

Comment: Contactless payments (up to £30) are also common in the UK, if your card has this feature it can help you buy on the go eg in the Underground. You may get better answers if you state where you plan to go in the UK - it’s small but regional differences do exist.

Comment: @Traveller Only Visa, Mastercard and Amex contactless cards are accepted by TfL. https://tfl.gov.uk/fares-and-payments/contactless/what-are-contactless-payment-cards

Comment: I think you will find that some places will take it but that acceptance is far from universal. Especially as you get away from major cities that handle large numbers of foriegners.

Answer (score 2):

[CreditCards.com](http://uk.creditcards.com/guides/what-is-jcb.php), an independent, unaffiliated resource about credit cards in the United Kingdom, has this report on JCB:

> **Can I use a JCB credit card in the UK?**
>
> Leading supermarkets like Sainsbury's accept JCB, as do many shops and restaurants in London, like the East India Company, Emma Bridgewater, Ichiryu, Hawes & Curtis & Neal’s Yard.
>
> Many UK based online retailers also accept JCB payment via Adyen, Elavon, SagePay, Wirecard, and Worldpay, as do merchants using mobile payment technology (like beauticians, builder, hairdressers, etc.) through iZettle.

For cash points, JCB global website notes:

**[ATM](https://www.global.jcb/en/consumers/about-atm/)**

> As a JCB cardmember you can get cash in the local currency at ATMs around the world. All you need is your card and your PIN number to get a cash advance service. Look for one of these marks on the ATM: JCB logo and Cirrus logo

[**Debit Card**](https://www.global.jcb/en/products/cards/)

> JCB Debit Cards withdraw transaction funds directly from your savings account at the point of use. They can be used at JCB merchants all over the world.

[**JCB Licensed Partners: United Kingdom**](http://www.jcbeurope.eu/merchants/accept/europe.html)

> Barclays Bank PLC
>   Checkout.com
>   Elavon Merchant Services
>   First Data Europe Limited
>   First Merchant Processing (Ireland) Limited
>   Lloyds Cardnet PLC
>   SIX Payment Services (Europe) S.A.
>   WorldPay (UK) Limited
>   JCB International (Europe) Ltd.